# Open window (or dialog) to block main window without stopping further instructions

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog

I have a `MainWindow` that will with the click of the button do some calculations that might take a few seconds.
During that time I would like to show a little dialog (or separate window) saying "Please wait..." in the middle of `MainWindow` that will fully block it, so the user is not able to do anything until this dialog is closed.
I tried creating a window and opening it with `window.ShowDialog();` but that will of course not continue the instructions...

Is there any other way that will work?

Comment: So you want the dialog to be modal (block interaction with other windows), while allowing a calculation process to run in the background?

Comment: That is the point, I do not want to start another thread for the calculations, because all the data I need is actually within the main thread. I simply want to lock the main window for the few seconds.

Comment: Theres no reason that you couldn't pass the data to the new thread.  To me, the multi threaded approach would be far more natural and less complicated then trying to simulate similar functionality on your own using some alternative method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is very straightforward - you should set your MainForm as a parent in the Show (not ShowDialog, as you noticed), and then call Enabled = false on your own form:

```
        Form2 f = new Form2();
        f.Show(this);
        this.Enabled = false;

        //do your stuff here

        f.Hide();
        this.Enabled = true;
        f.Dispose();
        f = null;
```

The only problem here is that you cannot cancel your process... But if your calculation is in another thread, the other form's controls will trigger their handlers and you can cancel the work in the other thread.

Comment: There is no cancellation needed, thank you that is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: A problem is that `this.Enabled = false` blocks also a window manager's actions. I.e. one can't move a window somewhere until it is unlocked. Are here a more elegant solution?

Comment: @Hi-Angel You can disable all controls in the `this` form, which still leaves the form able to move. Maybe. You can try it. But that is not what phil13131 wanted...

Comment: `ShowDialog` blocks all windows of the application. The code in this answer only blocks one specific window. So it's not fully equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

How about starting the calculations on another thread before opening the window?

You could possibly also create a new [`DispatcherFrame`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherframe.aspx) for your calculations.

Or show a `Popup` and set `IsEnabled` on a control close to the root to `false`.

Or move your code to an event on the dialog, like `Loaded`.

Comment: Yes, I thought of starting another thread, but I think that might just be unneccessarily complicated. How does a DispatcherFrame work? In general I would like to stay in my MainWindow thread, if that is possible...

Comment: @phil13131: It's kind of complicated, i would suggst reading the documentation, you might also find info on it [elsewhere](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx).

Comment: The Popup approach is more or less what I am doing now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code

Without blocking

In your code

```
    ....
    Thread newThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Create));
    newThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    newThread.IsBackground = true;
    newThread.Start();
    ....
}

private void Create()
{
    Window1 tempWindow = new Window1();
    tempWindow.Show();       
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
}
```

Blocking your main window

You can also use `Prism` framework, and use `InteractionRequest` class, in order to generate your windows

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405494%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx

Comment: But this does not block the main window. I know I could start a thread in the background, the point is that I actually want to block the main window for that time, without leaving its thread for the calculations.